# Will A Line Of Code Finish Before Executing The Next Line Of Code?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

The following codes is moving a file as long as the file doesn't already exist. If it does, it won't move the file.

My question is regarding the `File.Move`. When will the msgbox display? Will it display once the file is completely moved or will it display right after the `File.Move` line is executed.

Depending on the file size, it may take awhile to move the file and thus I don't want the msgbox to display until the file is moved completely.

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
        For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\Temp\", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.zip")
            Dim foundFileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(foundFile)

            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Transfer\" & foundFileInfo.Name) Then
                Msgbox("File already exists and will not moved!")
                Exit Sub
            Else
                File.Move(foundFile, "C:\Transfer\" & foundFileInfo.Name)
                Msgbox("File has been moved!")
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Ok, I had a feeling it would finish but wanted to be sure before running the line of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accordingly to [this source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx), the `File.Move`call is synchronous, which means that your msgbox will be shown only after the file is moved, regardless of its size.

For completeness, if you don't want to block the UI, you can try something like this:

```
' This must be placed outside your sub/function
Delegate Sub MoveDelegate(iSrc As String, iDest As String)

' This line and the following go inside your sub/function
Dim f As MoveDelegate = AddressOf File.Move

' Call File.Move asynchronously
f.BeginInvoke(
    foundFile, 
    "C:\Transfer\" & foundFile, 
    New AsyncCallback(Sub(r As IAsyncResult)
                          ' this code is executed when the move is complete
                          MsgBox("File has been moved!")
                      End Sub), Nothing)
```

or you can explore the new [async / await](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/10/30/what-is-visual-studio-async.aspx) instructions.

Answer (score 3):

File.Move is a synchronous operation, so the application will not execute the next line of code (your messagebox) until the move is complete.

As you indicated, if the file is large (and you are moving across drives) the messagebox will not show up until the file move is complete.  This can create a poor user experience, as your GUI will appear to be non-responsive during this time.

I would recommend taking the time to learn how to utilize background threads or async/await calls to perform the operation in the background.

There is a good article on Asynchronous IO on MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys.aspx

Finally you could also use the FileSystem object's [MoveFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh3171xd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method, which can pop up a file move UI for you, if you are just worried about keeping your UI responsive:

```
FileSystem.MoveFile(sourceFileName, destinationFileName, UIOption.AllDialogs)
```

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately, the code is executed line after the other so the `Msgbox` will pop up as long as the file has been completely moved.

if you want to monitor the progress, [visit this link for more details](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/qt/prgsbar.htm).

Answer (score 2):

The Message box will be displayed after the file is completely moved irrespective of the file size.

Answer (score 1):

Unless a method is asynchronous, a line of code will always finish executing before proceeding with the next line.

Note, if the file move is slow, and it holding up your program is a Bad Thing, then you could do the move in a background thread using for instance a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).